# *A ton* vs *tons of*

Tags: phrase-usage

Is there a preferred or more common usage between the phrase "with a ton of xxx" or "with tons of xxx"? Both referring to something having an abundance of something.

Comment: "tons of" is more common.

Comment: If you're English, perhaps *with a smidge more X*. If you're a New Yorker, *with a ton of X*. If you're a Valley Girl, *with like a billion tons of X, or whatever*.

Comment: What does your research show?

Comment: the second phrase is just more emphatic.  You said it yourself, abundance, and more than one ton would be even more abundant, overabundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following ngram, "tons of" is the most common:

*Source: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20ton%20of%2Ctons%20of%2Ca%20tonne%20of%2Ctonnes%20of&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%20ton%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20ton%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20ton%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctons%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btons%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTons%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ca%20tonne%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20tonne%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20tonne%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20Tonne%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctonnes%20of%3B%2Cc0)*

[image]

Comment: That only shows that people more often ship tons of things than a single ton of it.

Comment: @thmj1332 that's the first times I've ever seen Ngam chart look that. It's very clear. How did you manage to compress the dates, and resize the text?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, you just need to shrink the size of your browser window and then click Refresh.  In this way, the text size is larger relative to the overall size of the graph.  I wish more people knew this!

Comment: @thomj1332 that is nothing short of b.r.i.l.l.i.a.n.t. Oh, I might even retrace all my old answers and use this ingenious workaround on my Ngram charts. mind "explodes"

Comment: @Mari-Lou A and all, Yes.  Good idea.  And, it doesn't have to be the original author who makes the changes.  If folks want to go back and edit any previous illegible Ngram graphs with the better visualization, you get +2 credits for each one!  I just did it on this one to see how it was received.  Glad it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are interchangeable, but here's how I usually use them:

**A ton of**: countable objects.

**Tons of**: uncountable objects.

*Such-and-so candidate for mayor has tons of charm, but is a little light on the issues*.  Explanation: *charm* isn't countable.

*She's already got a ton of stuffed animals, let's get her something else for her birthday*.  Explanation: the stuffed animals are countable.

(Yes, you could also say *tons of stuffed animals*.)

Answer (score 1):

The use of "tons of something" by LONGMAN Dictionary is given in URL.

## tons of "something"

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tons-of-something

Therefore, the phrase of "tons of ..." also supports both countable plural noun and uncountable singular noun.